# Font in harvmac title

Tags: fonts, fontsize

[harvmac](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/harvmac) is an old set of macros for scientific documents in plain TeX. I can't figure out what font is used for the title produced by harvmac, and how I could use the same font in LaTeX. Here's an example:

```
\input harvmac
\Title{}{Your title goes here}
\end
```

You need to compile this with plain TeX, and you get this:

[image]

As you can see the font is slightly thicker than normal (i.e. thicker than what you'd get by using `\huge` or `\Huge` in LaTeX), but it is not bold.

This font is some variant of Computer Modern. How can I use the same font in LaTeX?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `\show\titlerm` which says:

```
> \titlerm=select font cmr10 at 17.28pt.
```

in other words it's a scaled cmr10 rather than cmr17 which latex would give you by default

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmr}{mx}{n}%
     {<->cmr10}{}

 \DeclareMathAlphabet {\mathzzz}{OT1}{cmr}{mx}{n}

\begin{document}

\showoutput

\Huge

Hello World

\fontseries{mx}\selectfont

Hello World


$\mathrm{xxxx}$

$\mathzzz{xxxx}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Is it possible to use the scaled version in math mode too?

Comment: @AndyS `\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathzzz}{OT1}{cmr}{mx}{n}` probably works

Comment: This throws an error: Encoding scheme `cmr' unknown.

Comment: @AndyS, no it doesn't:-) See updated answer

Comment: You're right, there's no error!

Answer (score 3):

Just to explain the background to the accepted answer: `harvmac.tex` sets `cmr10` as the title font and then scales it by `\magstep3` (resulting in 17.28pt).
Here is a plain TeX MWE that demonstrates the difference between the scaled-up `cmr10`, unscaled `cmr17`, and default `cmr10`.

The code is excerpted from the original `harvmac.tex`, lines 77 (\Title definition), and 244-258 (the section beginning "Unpleasantness in calling in abstract and title fonts"!).

This is compiled with `tex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf`.

```
\edef\tfontsize{ scaled\magstep3}
\font\titlerm=cmr10 \tfontsize
\def\titlefont{\def\rm{\fam0\titlerm}\textfont0=\titlerm \rm}
\def\Title#1{{\titlefont #1}}

\Title{Title Font cmr10 scaled by magstep 3 (17.28pt)}

\vskip 12pt

\font\titlerm=cmr17 
\Title{Title Font cmr17 no scaling}

\vskip 12pt

Normal text font cmr10

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: One has just to add `\font\titlerm=cmr17` after `\input harvmac`.